# Do goblins activate spring traps?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I know from reading the ingame info on goblins that they are too fast for spring traps, but does this mean that they activate spring traps but are too fast to get thrown off the map, or that they do not activate the traps at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They activate spring traps, but usually can run past the trap.  An example of a goblin being hit is if the spring trap is right next to a collector or storage, and the goblin goes to attack the building.

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Spring_Trap)

Comment: Also if goblins deployed in sequence, first goblin will activate trap and other following goblins will fly.(not all)

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow player of C.O.C., I know a lot from experience. Goblins do, however, activate spring traps, although they are not affected by them.

Comment: Why was my post edited?

Comment: Self promotion is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers/59302#59302).

Comment: Tis not self promotion but clan promotion. Plus, I was saying I was glad to help. Is this frowned upon?

Comment: You are still promoting something *you* would personally profit from.

Comment: @Sparow You may [use your profile](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/76421) for shout outs :)

Comment: The glad to help part too?

Comment: @Sparrow The glad to help part wasn't against any rules, but I assume it just got removed along with the advertisement. But that's okay because it wasn't actually a part of the answer part of your answer :)

Comment: @Bunyip Okay, thanks. I'll be sure to answer better next time.